# Android: show this screen on start up checkbox?

Tags: android, android-activity

On my main activity screen that is launched when the app launches, I have some details about how the app works, etc, and the user clicks "Let's start" - which jumps into the primary application activity screen.

I would like add a checkbox on the initial screen with the label "Show this screen on start up", and the checkbox is selected by default. If the user deselects it, the next time the app is run, it skips this screen and goes straight to the primary application screen.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can show an alert when the app starts with your default checkbox and load an initial selection from SharedPreferences. (For example, a "false" flag)

Only when the user changes the selection, save the new value to SharedPreferences again. (Change to "true")

Afterwards, the user will not see the dialog on stratup because of the saved value from SharedPreferences.

Based on your value from SharedPreferences do what you want in onCreate function or wherever you need.